# Cannot init vagrant with CentOS 7 (OpenGL Installation error)

Tags: vagrant, centos7

I'm completely new with Vagrant. When I try to init a CentOS7 on a VM with Vagrant, i'm getting thiserror:

Building the OpenGL support module[FAILED]
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong. The module is not built but the others are.)

I'm building the VM on Windows 8. Here is the complete trace.:

```
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin>vagrant.exe up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'centos/7' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'centos/7'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/centos/7
==> default: Adding box 'centos/7' (v1611.01) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/centos/boxes/7/versions/1611.01/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Progress: 100% (Rate: 2043k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> default: Successfully added box 'centos/7' (v1611.01) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'centos/7'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: bin_default_1485908630832_64930
"rsync" could not be found on your PATH. Make sure that rsync
is properly installed on your system and available on the PATH.

C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin>vagrant.exe up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
"rsync" could not be found on your PATH. Make sure that rsync
is properly installed on your system and available on the PATH.

C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin>vagrant.exe up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
"rsync" could not be found on your PATH. Make sure that rsync
is properly installed on your system and available on the PATH.

C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin>vagrant.exe up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: No guest additions were detected on the base box for this VM! Guest
    default: additions are required for forwarded ports, shared folders, host only
    default: networking, and more. If SSH fails on this machine, please install
    default: the guest additions and repackage the box to continue.
    default:
    default: This is not an error message; everything may continue to work properly,
    default: in which case you may ignore this message.
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /home/vagrant/sync => C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` home_vagrant_sync /home/vagrant/sync
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` home_vagrant_sync /home/vagrant/sync

The error output from the last command was:

mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'

C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin>vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
Installing the 'vagrant-vbguest' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-vbguest (0.13.0)'!

C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin>vagrant.exe up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...

C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin>vagrant.exe up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin>vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
[default] No installation found.
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.airenetworks.es
 * extras: centos.mirror.xtratelecom.es
 * updates: centos.mirror.xtratelecom.es
Package binutils-2.25.1-22.base.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.82-23.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package bzip2-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-11.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.8.5-11.el7 for package: gcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.4()(64bit) for package: gcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: gcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-514.2.2.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl.x86_64 4:5.16.3-291.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-291.el7 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Socket) >= 1.3 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Scalar::Util) >= 1.10 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-macros for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-libs for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(threads::shared) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(threads) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(constant) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Time::Local) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Time::HiRes) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Storable) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Socket) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Scalar::Util) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Simple::XHTML) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Simple::Search) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Getopt::Long) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Filter::Util::Call) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Temp) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec::Unix) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec::Functions) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Path) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Exporter) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Cwd) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Carp) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libperl.so()(64bit) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-157.el7_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.17-157.el7_3.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package mpfr.x86_64 0:3.1.1-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Carp.noarch 0:1.26-244.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Exporter.noarch 0:5.68-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-File-Path.noarch 0:2.09-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-File-Temp.noarch 0:0.23.01-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Filter.x86_64 0:1.49-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Getopt-Long.noarch 0:2.40-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Usage) >= 1.14 for package: perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-2.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Text::ParseWords) for package: perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-2.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-PathTools.x86_64 0:3.40-5.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Pod-Simple.noarch 1:3.28-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Escapes) >= 1.04 for package: 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Encode) for package: 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-Scalar-List-Utils.x86_64 0:1.27-248.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Socket.x86_64 0:2.010-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Storable.x86_64 0:2.45-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64 4:1.9725-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Time-Local.noarch 0:1.2300-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-constant.noarch 0:1.27-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-libs.x86_64 4:5.16.3-291.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.16.3-291.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-threads.x86_64 0:1.87-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-threads-shared.x86_64 0:1.43-6.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-157.el7_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64
---> Package perl-Encode.x86_64 0:2.51-7.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Pod-Escapes.noarch 1:1.04-291.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Pod-Usage.noarch 0:1.63-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Text) >= 3.15 for package: perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Pod-Perldoc for package: perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-Text-ParseWords.noarch 0:3.29-4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-514.6.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Pod-Perldoc.noarch 0:3.20-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(parent) for package: perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(HTTP::Tiny) for package: perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-podlators.noarch 0:2.5.1-3.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-HTTP-Tiny.noarch 0:0.033-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-parent.noarch 1:0.225-244.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                    Arch       Version                Repository   Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 gcc                        x86_64     4.8.5-11.el7           base         16 M
 kernel-devel               x86_64     3.10.0-514.2.2.el7     updates      13 M
 perl                       x86_64     4:5.16.3-291.el7       base        8.0 M
Installing for dependencies:
 cpp                        x86_64     4.8.5-11.el7           base        5.9 M
 glibc-devel                x86_64     2.17-157.el7_3.1       updates     1.1 M
 glibc-headers              x86_64     2.17-157.el7_3.1       updates     668 k
 kernel-headers             x86_64     3.10.0-514.6.1.el7     updates     4.8 M
 libmpc                     x86_64     1.0.1-3.el7            base         51 k
 mpfr                       x86_64     3.1.1-4.el7            base        203 k
 perl-Carp                  noarch     1.26-244.el7           base         19 k
 perl-Encode                x86_64     2.51-7.el7             base        1.5 M
 perl-Exporter              noarch     5.68-3.el7             base         28 k
 perl-File-Path             noarch     2.09-2.el7             base         26 k
 perl-File-Temp             noarch     0.23.01-3.el7          base         56 k
 perl-Filter                x86_64     1.49-3.el7             base         76 k
 perl-Getopt-Long           noarch     2.40-2.el7             base         56 k
 perl-HTTP-Tiny             noarch     0.033-3.el7            base         38 k
 perl-PathTools             x86_64     3.40-5.el7             base         82 k
 perl-Pod-Escapes           noarch     1:1.04-291.el7         base         51 k
 perl-Pod-Perldoc           noarch     3.20-4.el7             base         87 k
 perl-Pod-Simple            noarch     1:3.28-4.el7           base        216 k
 perl-Pod-Usage             noarch     1.63-3.el7             base         27 k
 perl-Scalar-List-Utils     x86_64     1.27-248.el7           base         36 k
 perl-Socket                x86_64     2.010-4.el7            base         49 k
 perl-Storable              x86_64     2.45-3.el7             base         77 k
 perl-Text-ParseWords       noarch     3.29-4.el7             base         14 k
 perl-Time-HiRes            x86_64     4:1.9725-3.el7         base         45 k
 perl-Time-Local            noarch     1.2300-2.el7           base         24 k
 perl-constant              noarch     1.27-2.el7             base         19 k
 perl-libs                  x86_64     4:5.16.3-291.el7       base        688 k
 perl-macros                x86_64     4:5.16.3-291.el7       base         43 k
 perl-parent                noarch     1:0.225-244.el7        base         12 k
 perl-podlators             noarch     2.5.1-3.el7            base        112 k
 perl-threads               x86_64     1.87-4.el7             base         49 k
 perl-threads-shared        x86_64     1.43-6.el7             base         39 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  3 Packages (+32 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 53 M
Installed size: 130 M
Downloading packages:
Public key for glibc-headers-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm is not installed
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates/packages/glibc-headers-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for libmpc-1.0.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                              2.6 MB/s |  53 MB  00:20
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Importing GPG key 0xF4A80EB5:
 Userid     : "CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>"
 Fingerprint: 6341 ab27 53d7 8a78 a7c2 7bb1 24c6 a8a7 f4a8 0eb5
 Package    : centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : mpfr-3.1.1-4.el7.x86_64                                     1/35
  Installing : libmpc-1.0.1-3.el7.x86_64                                   2/35
  Installing : cpp-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64                                     3/35
  Installing : 1:perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch                          4/35
  Installing : perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch                           5/35
  Installing : perl-podlators-2.5.1-3.el7.noarch                           6/35
  Installing : perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch                          7/35
  Installing : 1:perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-291.el7.noarch                      8/35
  Installing : perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64                               9/35
  Installing : perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch                     10/35
  Installing : perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch                           11/35
  Installing : perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64                             12/35
  Installing : perl-Storable-2.45-3.el7.x86_64                            13/35
  Installing : perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch                            14/35
  Installing : perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch                            15/35
  Installing : perl-Time-Local-1.2300-2.el7.noarch                        16/35
  Installing : perl-Socket-2.010-4.el7.x86_64                             17/35
  Installing : perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch                              18/35
  Installing : 4:perl-Time-HiRes-1.9725-3.el7.x86_64                      19/35
  Installing : perl-threads-shared-1.43-6.el7.x86_64                      20/35
  Installing : perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64                           21/35
  Installing : perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64                 22/35
  Installing : 4:perl-libs-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64                          23/35
  Installing : 4:perl-macros-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64                        24/35
  Installing : 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch                        25/35
  Installing : perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch                        26/35
  Installing : perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch                           27/35
  Installing : perl-Filter-1.49-3.el7.x86_64                              28/35
  Installing : perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-2.el7.noarch                         29/35
  Installing : 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64                               30/35
  Installing : kernel-headers-3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64                   31/35
  Installing : glibc-headers-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64                      32/35
  Installing : glibc-devel-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64                        33/35
  Installing : gcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64                                    34/35
  Installing : kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64                     35/35
  Verifying  : perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch                           1/35
  Verifying  : perl-threads-shared-1.43-6.el7.x86_64                       2/35
  Verifying  : perl-Storable-2.45-3.el7.x86_64                             3/35
  Verifying  : perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64                              4/35
  Verifying  : perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch                             5/35
  Verifying  : perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch                             6/35
  Verifying  : perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64                            7/35
  Verifying  : cpp-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64                                     8/35
  Verifying  : 1:perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-291.el7.noarch                      9/35
  Verifying  : glibc-headers-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64                      10/35
  Verifying  : 1:perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch                         11/35
  Verifying  : perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch                        12/35
  Verifying  : 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch                        13/35
  Verifying  : perl-Time-Local-1.2300-2.el7.noarch                        14/35
  Verifying  : perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch                         15/35
  Verifying  : perl-Socket-2.010-4.el7.x86_64                             16/35
  Verifying  : glibc-devel-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64                        17/35
  Verifying  : perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch                              18/35
  Verifying  : 4:perl-Time-HiRes-1.9725-3.el7.x86_64                      19/35
  Verifying  : perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64                 20/35
  Verifying  : libmpc-1.0.1-3.el7.x86_64                                  21/35
  Verifying  : 4:perl-libs-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64                          22/35
  Verifying  : 4:perl-macros-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64                        23/35
  Verifying  : kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64                     24/35
  Verifying  : perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch                           25/35
  Verifying  : perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64                              26/35
  Verifying  : kernel-headers-3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64                   27/35
  Verifying  : perl-podlators-2.5.1-3.el7.noarch                          28/35
  Verifying  : perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-2.el7.noarch                         29/35
  Verifying  : perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch                           30/35
  Verifying  : 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64                               31/35
  Verifying  : mpfr-3.1.1-4.el7.x86_64                                    32/35
  Verifying  : perl-Filter-1.49-3.el7.x86_64                              33/35
  Verifying  : perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch                     34/35
  Verifying  : gcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64                                    35/35

Installed:
  gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-11.el7        kernel-devel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-514.2.2.el7
  perl.x86_64 4:5.16.3-291.el7

Dependency Installed:
  cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-11.el7
  glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-157.el7_3.1
  glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-157.el7_3.1
  kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-514.6.1.el7
  libmpc.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.el7
  mpfr.x86_64 0:3.1.1-4.el7
  perl-Carp.noarch 0:1.26-244.el7
  perl-Encode.x86_64 0:2.51-7.el7
  perl-Exporter.noarch 0:5.68-3.el7
  perl-File-Path.noarch 0:2.09-2.el7
  perl-File-Temp.noarch 0:0.23.01-3.el7
  perl-Filter.x86_64 0:1.49-3.el7
  perl-Getopt-Long.noarch 0:2.40-2.el7
  perl-HTTP-Tiny.noarch 0:0.033-3.el7
  perl-PathTools.x86_64 0:3.40-5.el7
  perl-Pod-Escapes.noarch 1:1.04-291.el7
  perl-Pod-Perldoc.noarch 0:3.20-4.el7
  perl-Pod-Simple.noarch 1:3.28-4.el7
  perl-Pod-Usage.noarch 0:1.63-3.el7
  perl-Scalar-List-Utils.x86_64 0:1.27-248.el7
  perl-Socket.x86_64 0:2.010-4.el7
  perl-Storable.x86_64 0:2.45-3.el7
  perl-Text-ParseWords.noarch 0:3.29-4.el7
  perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64 4:1.9725-3.el7
  perl-Time-Local.noarch 0:1.2300-2.el7
  perl-constant.noarch 0:1.27-2.el7
  perl-libs.x86_64 4:5.16.3-291.el7
  perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.16.3-291.el7
  perl-parent.noarch 1:0.225-244.el7
  perl-podlators.noarch 0:2.5.1-3.el7
  perl-threads.x86_64 0:1.87-4.el7
  perl-threads-shared.x86_64 0:1.43-6.el7

Complete!
Copy iso file C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.4 - guest version is unknown
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.4 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules[  OK  ]
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
Building the main Guest Additions module[  OK  ]
Building the shared folder support module[  OK  ]
Building the OpenGL support module[FAILED]
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong. The module is not built but the others are.)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions[  OK  ]
Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions [  OK  ]
Installing the Window System drivers
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.4. Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /home/vagrant/sync => C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chown `id -u vagrant`:`id -g vagrant` /home/vagrant/sync

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

chown: changing ownership of '/home/vagrant/sync': Not a directory
```

Comment: did you `Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong` ?

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. I thought that because that error, the CentOS wasn't build. Could you tell me if it's possible to access to the CentOS? Maybe building the image in Oracle VirtualBox?

Comment: run `vagrant ssh` to ssh into your VM - if vagrant does not ssh into it, open VirtualBox and access it form there, your VM is definitly running

Comment: Ok, I'll try it this evening. I'll come to you with the results, thank you very much.